# Deriving rectifier matching loss

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, neural-networks

I am trying to learn more about how the rectifier activation function $h(x)=max(0,x)$ works mathematically. How would I go about deriving the matching loss for this function? The matching loss is $ΔH(w⋅x,h^{−1}(y))$ as loss of $w$ on $(x,y)$, and $h=\nabla H$. The loss is (I think) the Bregman divergence:

\begin{align*}
\int_{h^{−1}(y)}^{w⋅x} (h(z)-y) dz &= H(w⋅x) - H(h^{−1}(y)) - (w⋅x - h^{−1}(y))y\\
&= ΔH(w⋅x,h^{−1}(y))
\end{align*}

I have seen some examples for other activation functions, but not the rectifier function. For example, for the transfer function $h(z)=sign(z)$, $H(z) = |z|$, and the matching loss is $max\{0,-yw⋅x\}$ (a hinge loss).

Sorry, still a little new. Does that explain the problem?